# PHP Index.php change title

Tags: php, web

In my website i cannot seem to change the title in the index.php page, i did not create this code so i did not initially make the title, the index.php looks like this `

```
$result = mysql_query ("SELECT * FROM news ORDER BY i DESC"); 
while ($new = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){ $news[] = $new; }  
$smarty->assign('iplogged', $news);
$smarty->display("class.index.tpl");
$smarty->display("class.footer.tpl");
?>
```

The title is vDod - Dashboard but i want to change it, i do not know how, editing anything in that code there will give me an error on all pages, stating 'Direct Access Not Allowed'

Answer (score 0):

All good! I found the Title Prefix in init.php, so i managed to change the title prefix which solved it.

Comment: This is not an answer, it does not belong in the answer section, please move this to a Question Edit or a comment.